# How to download/print specific portion of a page using php

Tags: php, javascript

I have an HTML page as follows

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
<table>
    <th>WEEK</th>
    <th>DATES</th>
    <th>Workout #1</th>
    <th>Workout #2</th>
    <th>Workout #3</th>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3/27-4/2</td>
        <td>Warm up for 5 minutes. </td>
        <td>Same as #1 for this week.</td>
        <td>Same as #1 for this week.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4/3-4/9</td>
        <td>Warm up for 5 minutes. </td>
        <td>Same as #1 for this week.</td>
        <td>Same as #1 for this week.</td>
    </tr></table>
```

How can make only the table downloadable and printable using php and/or javascript.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26114555/3944217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a print stylesheet that sets everything but the table to `display: none`. The browser takes care of printing, not your code, and uses your print stylesheet when doing so.

Answer (score 13):

do you want to print a part of the web page?
do you have multiple print buttons in a web page, which prints portion of the page?
do you want to exclude some elements in print of your page? (like images, ads)
do you want to print the display page differently? (changing font or colors of text)
Here, I am going to give code examples to above questions

Let us take a sample HTML web page

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Header Content</div>
        <div id="content">actual content</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer content</div>
        <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage();"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you want to print the whole page then

```
<script language="javascript">
    function printPage() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

To Print a part of the web page:
– create a print window and write html text you wanted to print
– focus the window and call the “print()” function
– close the print window

Here is the modified printPage function

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage('content');"></input>
function printPage(id) {
    var html="<html>";
    html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    html+="</html>";
    var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```

You can hide some of the elements within your actual content by adding style elements or

### include css file in print window html

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="ads"> Ad content</div>
    actual content
    <img src="example.gif" />
</div>
----
function printPage(id) {
    var html="<html>";
    html+="<head>";
    html+="<style type='text/css'>#content div.ads, #content img {display:none}    </style>";
    html+="<link rel='Stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media='print' />";
    html+="</head>";
    html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    html+="</html>";
.....
}
```

In the above example, I have added style and css file, you can use either one or both. Using
these styles or css, we can style the text only for print.
If you have multiple print buttons, and each one prints selected area of a web page, then you
need to pass id of the print area on each button click.

```
<div id="area1">Area1 content</div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage('area1');"></input>
<div id="area2">Area2 content</div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage('area2');"></input>
```

Just change the fields with your requirements

Comment: Very thorough and nice answer!