# How to print data retrieved from mysql via printer in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print mysql data which is retrieve from mysql via printer ...

Please donot answer it CTRL + P ...

i want a button which can send all the retrieve data of mysql to printer ... I should be able to print the data via printer ...

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about printing on the server, or on a users system via the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already answered. Use the solution given in following link:

[How to print a page in PHP to print using printer same as window.print() works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114277/how-to-print-a-page-in-php-to-print-using-printer-same-as-window-print-works)

The variable `$html`variable in this link should contain the data fetched from Mysql(as in your case).

like

```
$html="<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Description</td></tr>";

mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, desc FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
$html.="<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";
}

$html.="</table>";
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: lol..Thanks I work with PDO only and I used mysqli long back :-) ..The purpose was to give the idea and not the exact code as the question seems very basic..Good catch though :-)